# Regular Expression: capture multiple lines up to a pattern

Tags: regex

I'm trying to build a regular expression that can capture a group of lines. The text looks like this:

```
03/09/2021

line1

line2

04/09/2021

line3

line4

line5

05/09/2021

line3
```

I would like a regular expression to capture each of the three groups consisting of a date (dd/mm/yyyy) and a variable number of lines (each of these lines are made up of **random alphanumeric strings** made up of numbers, letters, spaces or even symbols). What I would like then to extract the following 3 groups:

```
03/09/2021

line1

line2
```

```
04/09/2021

line3

line4

line5
```

```
05/09/2021

line3
```

Comment: By definition alphanumeric characters do not include symbols other than letters and numbers. If you really allow *anything*, then date-like string may appear inside any line. Considering that regex for *valid* date itself is not very trivial...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this pattern: `(?:\d{2}\/){2}\d{4}(?:\s*\w+\s*)*(?=$)`

See Regex [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/pJZ9iz/2)

---

**Explanation**

- `(?:\d{2}\/){2}` Match two digits and a backslash, two times.
- `\d{4}` Match four digits (year)
- `(?:\s*\w+\s*)*` Match zero or more white space and any alphanumeric characters and again zero or more times white space. And as at the end of this part is a "*" the part can repeat zero or more times.
- `(?=\$)` Check after the match is the end of the string? if so then match.

Comment: Thanks but each line is made up of a random string (letters, numbers, spaces, etc ...). I have updated the question!

Answer (score 0):

Here is my proposal: `^\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4}$(?:.(?!^\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4}$))*`

And [examples](https://regex101.com/r/QHtgus/1).